# Django JSON Response to HTML Page Not Working

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, django

I have a Django project where I am trying to get AJAX working. I can't seem to send the JSON response to the HTML page. When I check the chrome console the JSON data is not returned only parses the HTML.

This is my Views.py where I have the cart logic defined:

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, "carts/carts.html", {"cart": cart_obj})


def cart_update(request):
    print("Hello")
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Product is gone")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
            added = False
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
            added = True
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_obj.products.count()
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("Ajax request")
            json_data = {
                "added": added,
                "removed": not added,
            }
            return JsonResponse(json_data)
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

This is javascript for the Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax")
    productForm.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Form is not sending")
        var thisForm = $(this)
        var actionEndpoint; thisForm.attr("action");
        var httpMethod; thisForm.attr("method");
        var formData; thisForm.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: actionEndpoint,
            method: httpMethod,
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("success")
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data.added)
                console.log(data.removed)
                console.log("Added", data.added)
                console.log("Removed", data.removed)
                var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
                if (data.added){
                    submitSpan.html("<button>Remove</button>")
                } else {
                    submitspan.html("<button>Add to Basket</button>")
                }
            },
            error: function(errorData){
                console.log("error")
                console.log(errorData)
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

Added screenshot of Chrome Inspector (Network Tab)

[image]

Comment: if you look at the Network tab of Chrome's inspector, what does it show for the request / response data ?

Comment: just document, script and xhr entries

Comment: just added screenshot

Comment: it looks like you are not even making the request in the first place. If you clear the network tab, and try the request, does a new row show up in the network log?

Comment: No nothing happens....

Comment: actually a new XHR entry pops up

Comment: if you click on that new entry, you should then see the details of the request and response. That has the useful info

Comment: ok sure, once I click onto it and then response, it has a copy of the HTML

Comment: The code was incorrect and not formatted